# how can I user d3 force tree layout,

Tags: javascript

I would like to use a collapsible force diagram which is collapsed by default (starting out with only one node). I ran across this: http://bl.ocks.org/david4096/6168323 but it is blank and not working. I'm using the latest Mozilla Firefox 43.0.4. I even put it to plunker with the same result - blank.

Can someone identify the problem?

Also would it be possible to have it partially collpased? That means the first set of children expanded but everything else collapsed?

My non-working example on plunker

Comment: Where is your Plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/n2FaIgRAfy4D1xgtJabN?p=preview

Comment: Don't put it here, edit your question and put the link there.

Comment: Please, edit your *question*.

Comment: Well, I give up...

Comment: I want to add two root nodes, and click on the root node 1 to display the node 1 of the child node, click on the node 11 to display his child nodes, and the two click events do not affect each other.please..